Use autocomplete drop-down filters in Django Admin back-end for normal fields (not ManyToMany or ForeignKey)
Is it possible to use an autocomplete filter class to be used in the list_filter for normal fields (i.e. not foreign keys or other relations)?
For example, for this model:
class Project(models.Model):

    project_number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)

I'd like to have an autocomplete filter in my admin back-end for the project_number field. Would admin_auto_filters be able to do that?
